# Is there a .NET wrapper for FMUs?

Tags: fmi

I need to co-simulate an FMU (generated from OpenModelica) within a .NET application. Is there a .NET equivalent to JFMI or PyFMI ?

Answer (score 1):

Way too late for the original poster I'm sure, but just in case it helps anyone else

Take a look at https://github.com/Tuebel/FmiWrapper